# Cabal missing dependency error

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
$ cabal install git-annex --force-reinstalls --bindir=$HOME/bin.local -f"-assistant -webapp -webdav -pairing -xmpp -dns"
...
Configuring git-annex-5.20140116...
Building git-annex-5.20140116...
Preprocessing executable 'git-annex' for git-annex-5.20140116...

Remote/External.hs:29:8:
    Could not find module `Control.Concurrent.STM'
    It is a member of the hidden package `stm-2.4.2'.
    Perhaps you need to add `stm' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    It is a member of the hidden package `stm-2.2.0.1'.
    Perhaps you need to add `stm' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
git-annex-5.20140116 failed during the building phase. The exception was: ExitFailure 1
$ cabal install stm --force-reinstalls --bindir=$HOME/bin.local
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
stm-2.4.2
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

How can I force Cabal to ignore the `Could not find module...` error and install `git-annex`?

Somebody else has reported the same problem [here](http://git-annex.branchable.com/bugs/__96__minimal_build__39____fails_due_to_missing_stm_dependency/). The developer said that it's fixed, but apparently it's not.

Comment: Possibly there hasn't been a release since the fix was made. Have you tried cloning the repo directly and installing from the current project head?

Comment: Don't `--force-reinstalls`. It's not going to fix the problem you're having, and it can easily cause serious problems down the line. Take a look at `ghc-pkg check` (watch for broken packages) to see if you've already caused problems for your future self.

Comment: I was using `--force-reinstalls` because Cabal refused to install another package (unrelated to STM) without that.

Comment: @Luke Taylor: How do I install from the current project head once it's cloned to my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error message describes the problem:

> ```
> Could not find module `Control.Concurrent.STM'
> It is a member of the hidden package `stm-2.4.2'.
> Perhaps you need to add `stm' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
> ```

So if you `cabal unpack git-annex`, cd into the directory, edit the cabal file to add stm to the build-depends, and then run `cabal install` from there, that should resolve the issue...